# Can I monkey patch function arguments/variables prior to calling the function?

Tags: python

I have a third party package which does this:

```
def build(debug=False):
    args = []
    if not (debug):
        args.append('--windowed')
    args.extend(['--icon', path('src/main/icons/Icon.ico')])
    # and much, much more
```

And I wish to monkey patch this function into becoming:

```
def build(debug=False, args=[]):
    # remove the line: args = []
    # and retain the rest of the function
```

I know I can for example do the following:

```
def monkeypatched_build(debug=False, args=[]):
    # remove the line: args = []
    # and include all of the other code here

build = monkeypatched_build
```

However, the `build` function in my case is complex, and I would like to avoid maintaining a separate version of this function, if possible, and just change the way I can modify the `args` variable.

I'm not sure this is possible, as I need to modify the function prior to calling it. Any ideas?

Comment: How is the `args` list populated in the existing code?

Comment: @lxop I added code which explains how args is populated to my original question.

Comment: If the original `build()` function only has a single (optional, at that) argument, then adding another optional argument to the original function won't break anything.

Comment: I'm not aware of a reasonable way to alter just some of the function code, unfortunately, short of loading the function bytecode and editing it

Answer (score 0):

for a potential solution that doesn't involve this hack, are you allowed to modify the build function whatsoever? if so, you can just add a flag argument to it with a default of true.

```
def build(debug=False, overwrite_flag = True, args = []):
    if overwrite_flag:
        args = []
    #rest of the function
```

As is however, what you are asking is essentially suppressing one of the instructions written in the function, and not just the addition of a new parameter. new parameters could be managed with decorators, but overruling a function's instructions is something i am not aware of.

Comment: Whenever I update this package with pip, my changes are lost with this approach. This is why my other alternative is better for me; copy the entire function and maintain it myself. However, this involves making a diff at any package update to check for changes. If possible, the diff checking will be minimal if I could somehow allow for a couple of minor tweaks to the function before calling it, if possible.

Comment: This function has a naughty bit - [mutable default parameter](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: That's what the op wants though for his "unusual" case, and for the original build function, the args is reassigned to an empty list, thus skipping around the issue. @lxop However, yes, it is good to be aware of it.

Comment: The fact that it is empty is not the naughty part, just that it is mutable. A safer approach would be use `args=None` then check for that in the function and replace with `[]`

Comment: the build function in OP's question behaves with an empty arg list initialized inside, and he wanted it to also support a mutable default. he wants two behaviours from one function, the flag can be set to provide that. @lxop We do not know more details about the OP's function to establish if that is necessary or not, so i cannot presume either ways. EDIT: Does that seem fair? Have i missed something?